# Why is console.log not a function in Shiny for R?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, shiny

I include `JavaScript` in `Shinys ui.R` like this:

```
tags$body(tags$script(src="someJs.js"))
```

Within my `someJs.js` I have a function

```
function someFunc1() {
    ....;
}

... some more code ...

console.log(variable1);
```

The `console.log` is **outside** of the function `soemFunc1()`. 
When I start the App and have a look at the console, I get

> console.log() is not a function.

Why is that?

I also load `d3` in the head `tags$head(tags$script(src="d3.v3.min.js"))`.
When I try `d3.select...` in the console, I also get

> d3 is not a function.

However, I use `d3` in my app for styling.

What is `Shiny` doing with the `js`. Is there an object where it attaches everything to?!

Here a an example, easy to reproduce.

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js")),
    tags$head(tags$script(src="test.js")),
            mainPanel(
                    tags$div(id = "test", "test test test")
            )
    )
```

)

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
```

create a `www` folder in the same directory where `server.R` and `ui.R` are and save a `js` file with the name `test.js` with the following content:

```
console.log("This will cause error")
```

Now, go ahead and open the console.
It says

> console.log() is not a function

Try type into the console of the browser `d3`. It says

> d3 is not a function.

Comment: The R console or JavaScript console?

Answer (score 5):

`console.log()` is a JavaScript function, so you cannot call it in R-Shiny and expect it to run in JavaScript. You have to explicitly tell Shiny to make that call in JavaScript.

Since it is a fairly common operation for me, I included it in the package [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs), you can call the `logjs()` function in R and it will write output to the javascript console.

Example:

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs() # Set up shinyjs
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        shinyjs::logjs("hello")
    }
)
```

Comment: I am aware of that. The thing is, that I call, as you can see in my question, `console.log()` in a `JavaScript file` which I then import into `shiny`. So in there I should be able to call `console.log()` since it gets interpreted from the browser... Have you tried to import a `js` file the way I did?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the way you wrote the question is confusing and hard to reproduce. It'd be a lot better if you provide a fully reproducible minimal example with the entire app code and the entire javascript file.  Even better, instead of including a separate javascript file, try first including javascript inline.  Otherwise it's going to be very hard to help you because I can't reproduce the error you're seeing

Comment: I think including many `js` files inline, that have many lines of code does not make the code more maintainable. I try to reproduce. Be back here soon

Comment: added an reproducible example

Comment: Yes using inline JS is not more maintainable, and you should use separate files in your app. But when posting on Stackoverflow it makes it much easier and simpler for us to have one code chunk that we can run rather than having to create two files to reproduce the code. Similarly, in my answer I used one code chunk for the entire app, where as in order to run your code I need to copy both chunks separately and deal with them... just little things that will make it a lot easier for others to help you without getting frustrated at the friction :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters or not, but there should be a semicolon at the end of the `console.log()` line. Anyway, I suggest you do two things to get better answers: 1. make your example **minimal**, so focus on the d3 javascript file OR on your own file, but don't include both in a minimal example, and 2. see if you still get an error when including the exact same JS code inline, because it will make people (at least myself) much more willing to test it out when there's no need to create multiple files

Comment: @DeanAttali Hi Dean, do you know of a straightforward example that display live and rolling R console log into a Shiny app ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to use `console.log()` in the JavaScript to see something in the JavaScript console then you shouldn't have a problem:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
      tags$script(HTML(
        "console.log('Here is some text');"
        ))
  )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

})
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you run this, and then inspect the page using Chrome or RStudio's web-browser, and click on console, which gives you the JavaScript console, you will see the output from the `console.log()` function.

If you want to print to the R console you have to use `print` or `cat` from the server.

Comment: have you tried to import ja `.js` file in the `ui.R` like I did?

Comment: added an reproducible example